# Form is displaying before async function completes

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, async-await, task

I've got a WinForms project that scans a given network and returns valid IP addresses.  Once all the addresses are found, I create a user control for each and place it on the form.  My functions to ping ip addresses use `async` and `Task` which I thought would "wait" to execute before doing something else, but it doesn't.  My form shows up blank, then within 5 seconds, all the user controls appear on the form.

Declarations:

```
private List<string> networkComputers = new List<string>();
```

Here's the Form_Load event:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load network computers.
    await LoadNetworkComputers();
    LoadWidgets();
}
```

The `LoadNetworkComputers` function is here:

```
private async Task LoadNetworkComputers()
{
    try
    {
        if (SplashScreenManager.Default == null)
        {
            SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(this, typeof(LoadingForm), false, true, false);
            SplashScreenManager.Default.SetWaitFormCaption("Finding computers");
        }
        else
            Utilities.SetSplashFormText(SplashForm.SplashScreenCommand.SetLabel, "Scanning network for computers.  This may take several minutes...");

        networkComputers = await GetNetworkComputers();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close "loading" window.
        SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(false);
    }
}
```

And the last 2 functions:

```
private async Task<List<string>> GetNetworkComputers()
{
    networkComputers.Clear();
    List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();
    List<string> computersFound = new List<string>();

    for (int i = StartIPRange; i <= EndIPRange; i++)
        ipAddresses.Add(IPBase + i.ToString());

    List<PingReply> replies = await PingAsync(ipAddresses);

    foreach(var reply in replies)
    {
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            computersFound.Add(reply.Address.ToString());
    }

    return computersFound;
}

private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<string> theListOfIPs)
{
    var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

I'm really stuck on why the form is being displayed before the code in the `MainForm_Load` event finishes.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that in the `LoadNetworkComputers` it loads a splash form which lets the user know that the app is running.  It's when the form shows up behind that, that I'm trying to avoid.  Here's a screenshot (sensitive info has been blacked out):
[image]

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but it is not the whole purpose of async/await to allow you code to continue while a lengthy operation is on course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason one would use async-await is to enable callers of functions to continue executing code whenever your function has to wait for something.

The nice thing is that this will keep your UI responsive, even if the awaitable function is not finished. For instance if you would have a button that would `LoadNetworkComputers` and `LoadWidgets` you would be glad that during this relatively long action your window would still be repainted.

Since you've defined your `Mainform_Load`as async, you've expressed that you want your UI to continue without waiting for the result of LoadNetWorkComputers.

[In this interview with Eric Lippert](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) (search in the middle for async-await) async-await is compared with a a cook making dinner. Whenever the cook finds that he has to wait for the bread to toast, he starts looking around to see if he can do something else, and starts doing it. After a while when the bread is toasted he continues preparing the toasted bread.

By keeping the form-load async, your form is able to show itself, and even show an indication that the network computers are being loaded.

An even nicer method would be to create a simple startup-dialog that informs the operator that the program is busy loading network computers. The async form-load of this startup-dialog could do the action and close the form when finished.

```
public class MyStartupForm
{
    public List<string> LoadedNetworkComputers {get; private set;}

    private async OnFormLoad()
    {
        // start doing the things async.
        // keep the UI responsive so it can inform the operator
        var taskLoadComputers = LoadNetworkComputers();
        var taskLoadWidgets = LoadWidgets();

        // while loading the Computers and Widgets: inform the operator
        // what the program is doing:
        this.InformOperator();

        // Now I have nothing to do, so let's await for both tasks to complete
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskLoadComputers, taskLoadWidgets});

        // remember the result of loading the network computers:
        this.LoadedNetworkComputers = taskLoadComputers.Result;

        // Close myself; my creator will continue:
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And your main form:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // show the startup form to load the network computers and the widgets
    // while loading the operator is informed
    // the form closes itself when done
    using (var form = new MyStartupForm())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);

        // fetch the loadedNetworkComputers from the form
        var loadedNetworkComputers = form.LoadedNetworkComputers;
        this.Process(loadedNetworkComputers);
    }
}
```

Now while loading, instead of your mainform the StartupForm is shown while the items are loaded.. The operator is informed why the main form is not showing yet. As soon as loading is finished, the StartupForm closes itself and loading of the main form continues

Answer (score 1):

> My form shows up blank, then within 5 seconds, all the user controls appear on the form.

This is by design. When the UI framework asks your app to display a form, it must do so *immediately*.

To resolve this, you'll need to decide what you *want* your app to look like while the `async` work is going on, initialize to that state on startup, and then *update* the UI when the `async` work completes. Spinners and loading pages are a common choice.